# Offline equivalent of google maps

Tags: google-maps

So I have this issue where I'm developing a local web application and sometimes I might not have internet access. I do know that GMaps isn't all that happy when it loses internet connection so I was wondering whether there's a way of saving the state of a part of google maps (tiles, markers and lines for a zone/city). Or a google map equivalent that would let me do something like that, by which I mean building graphical asses on a map zone and keep that state even if the uses loses internet connection

Answer (score 0):

There are several frameworks that enable an offline usage of OpenStreetMap, e.g. [osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) if you are working with Android.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I found all I needed here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Local_Tiles_Example